# firebase,FirebaseError: There was an exception while connecting to the authentication server: Host is unresolved: auth.firebase.com

Tags: android, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm developing an Android mobile application using Firebase.

In this application, I have a registration and login activity which I used default creating user account and login of Firebase.

It was working correctly until 2 days ago but today I keep receiving error:

```
FirebaseError: There was an exception while connecting to the authentication server: 
               Host is unresolved: auth.firebase.com"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Reolving a host error probabely occures when your device cannot see the server through network check your Network first.

Comment: Likely a proxy/networking issue.

Comment: Do you have this problem while running it in emulator or physical device?

Answer (score 0):

That error is reported when the Firebase client cannot establish a connection to the Firebase server.

Check your network connection, and any proxies or NAT devices that may be between you and Firebase.